# How can I set properties of a clone object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

I found a good tutorial about cloning objects on [this](http://www.tomauger.com/2009/flash-actionscript/actionscript-3-gotchas-copy-by-reference-deep-copy-and-read-only-objects) site (thanks to Andrey Popov). I've modified it, created a mc and a textfield. The problem is I can't set default values for the mc's and the textfield's properties. Here's my code:

```
var getReadOnlyValues:Function = function():Object { return {
    mc1: new box_1_1(),
    mc1: {
        name: "mc1_",
        alpha: 1,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 30,
        height: 25
    },
    mc1Text: new TextField(),
    mc1Text: {
        text: "test",
        x: 100.60,
        y: 80.50,
        selectable: false,
        multiline: false,
        wordWrap: false,
        defaultTextFormat: caption_tf
    }
}};

function addBoxes() {
    var copyOne:Object = getReadOnlyValues();
    copyOne.mc1.alpha = 1;
    copyOne.mc1.x = num;
    copyOne.mc1.width = 200;

    addChild(copyOne.mc1);
    copyOne.mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCaptionClick);

    copyOne.mc1.addChild(copyOne.mc1Text);
    copyOne.mc1Text.text = "test_" + num;
    copyOne.mc1Text.x = num;

    // traceObj(copyOne);
    // traceObj(getReadOnlyValues());
}
```

How can I set default values for the instances?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Clone an object or create a brand new one with initial values? Seems like the second. You cannot have the same property in an object twice (that's what you are currently doing: mc1: box_1_1 and mc1: Object; mc1Text: TextField and mc1Text: Object.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't understand what you mean by saying "cloning or creating a brand new one". Maybe both... What's the difference? I see that you understood the problem in code. I tried this: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/502537/ but it's giving me syntax error.

Comment: @nikel I don't understand what's your problem because your code is working fine for me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have written this to a comment but it would be too long so here I go:
You can create empty Objects like this:

```
var o1:Object = new Object(); //empty object with constructor call
var o2:Object = {}; //this is an empty object with object literal
```

You can then assign properties to an object:

```
o1.abc = "This is my abc string";
o1["abc"] = "This is my abc string"; //the same as above
```

If you create an object with an object literal, you can assing a property right away upon creation (this is not possible with the constructor call):

```
var o:Object = {
   prop1: "My prop",
   myMc: new Movieclip()
}
```

I will take your funcion now called `getReadOnlyValues`. This function returns an object which has properties. But in your case you are using property names twice:

```
    mc1: new box_1_1(),
    mc1: {
        name: "mc1_",
        alpha: 1,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 30,
        height: 25
    }
```

That is not correct. Property names must be unique (cos they are basically string identifiers). Also note that when you are trying to "set" mc1 again, you try to assign this property another Object (!) with the object literal ( `{}` ) and properties. But that's it, this object would have nothing to do with your `box_1_1` instance, it would be just an independent object. Same with the textfield. If you want to set values for instance of different classes, you would need to do it otherwise because you cannot just associate some values from an object to your movieclip 'out of thin air'. Here is an example how you could do it (note this is just to explain the idea of objects and properties):

```
var o1 = {
    mc: new MovieClip(),
    mcSettings: {
        x: 100,
        y: 300,
        alpha: 0.5
    }
}

var o2:Object = {
    mc: new MovieClip(),
    mcSettings: {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
        alpha: 0.3
    }
}

function setValues(o:Object):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = o.mc;
    var settings:Object = o.mcSettings;
    for(var i:String in settings) {
        mc[i] = settings[i]; //would be mc["x"] = 100, mc["y"] = 300, mc["alpha"] = 0.5 for o1
    }

    trace(mc.x, mc.y, mc.alpha);
}

setValues(o1);
setValues(o2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extend MovieClip and TextField, and define default values there...

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class MyMovieClip extends MovieClip
    {
        public function MyMovieClip()
        {
            super();

            x = 10;
            y = 10;
            name = "testName";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when created later, those values will be defined when they're constructed...

```
var myMovie:MovieClip = new MyMovieClip as MovieClip;
```